# stuck with R str_detect need the regex

Tags: r

```
## id,  name,  sex   ,    Case.Details     ,            type
## 1   A3 ,   M, 020319 entry, 030419 exit   ,  second gen AB-1
## 2   B5 ,male, 040819 in and 050819 out   ,   second gen AB-2
## 3   C8  ,  F ,081119 in                  ,   AB-1/2, (second gen)
```

I need to count the dates which are in the format "ddmmyy" within the Case.Details field in R I am stuck on the below line where I'm trying to get the regular expression for the `str_detect`. Please help me.

```
library(tibble)
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

date_counts <- df %>%
     distinct(Case.Details, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
     unnest_tokens(word, Case.Details, drop = FALSE) %>%
     distinct(id, word, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
     anti_join(stop_words, by = "word") %>%
     filter(str_detect(word, "[^\\d]")) %>%  # <--- Here is my problem
     group_by(word) %>%
     mutate(word_total = n()) %>%
     ungroup()

> word_counts <- date_counts %>%
> count(word, sort = TRUE)
> View(date_counts)
```

Comment: what the issue? do you get an error? can you please add the output from `dput(df)` to your question?

Comment: Sir, i dont get an error, i am not able to read date fields i want to count date fields 020319 and 030419 as 2 counts,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many 6-digit numbers appear in each element of the `case.detail` column do (in base R):

```
library(stringr)
df$count = sapply( str_match_all( df$case.details, "\\b\\d{6}\\b"), length)
```

Example:

```
df = structure(list(name = c("A3 ", "B5 ", "C8 "), 
                    sex = c(" M", " male", " F "), 
                    case.details = c(" 020319 entry, 030419 exit ", " 040819 in and 050819 out ", " 081119 in "), 
                    type = c(" second gen AB-1", " second gen AB-2"," AB-1/2, (second gen)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 

df$count = sapply(str_match_all(df$case.details, "\\b\\d{6}\\b"), length)
```

Result:

```
> df
  name   sex                case.details                  type count
1  A3      M  020319 entry, 030419 exit        second gen AB-1     2
2  B5   male   040819 in and 050819 out        second gen AB-2     2
3  C8     F                   081119 in   AB-1/2, (second gen)     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_count` from `stringr` to count number of times a pattern occurs in a string.

Using @R. Schifini's data

```
stringr::str_count(df$case.details, "\\d{6}")
#[1] 2 2 1
```